# Git clone / downloads history

Tags: linux, git, logging, computer-forensics

I have a problem with GIT logs. Is it possible to view the git-clone history in GIT or OS shell?  Where to find the history of clone and downloads GIT repository  with information about time, dest. IP?

Comment: It's pretty unclear for me what you are actually want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

The 'git clone' gives only a copy of the data, it does not do any change in the repo i.e. logging download history. However, I assume the git is accessed in some cerain way like via SSH or http/https. Then you can use the services which gave the access to the git to getch the data you require. For this reason they should be capable to gather, store and provide it to you.

As an exmple, for http/https you can use the logs of the web server (filtering by URL). For ssh you can use `last` by the user who clonned the repo. And so on.